# Trying to use ng-repeat, where am I going wrong?

Tags: angularjs

I have begun with the code from [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), and am slowly changing it. My goal is to make a simple spreadsheet application. In `angular-seed/app/index.html` I added the following code to begin with:

`<input type="text" ng-model="KID" placeholder="ID goes here">`

`<input type="text" ng-model="DESC" placeholder="Description goes here">`

`<input type="text" ng-model="DDD" placeholder="Drop Dead Date goes here">`

That did what I wanted, but I thought I would try to take what I have learned from the John Lindquist tutorial and apply it. So I changed the above:

`<span ng-repeat="entryField in entryFields">`

`<input type="text" ng-model="entryField.ngmodel" placeholder="entryField.pHolder">`

`</span>`

and I added the following controller to `angular-seed/app/js/controllers.js`

```
function DataEntryCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.entryFields = [
       {pHolder:'ID goes here',ngmodel:'KID'},
       {pHolder:'Description goes here',ngmodel:'DESC'},
       {pHolder:'Drop Dead Date goes here',ngmodel:'DDD'}
   ];
```

}

And now I only get one text field with the literal string `entryField.pHolder`. I first suspected I wasn't using the right syntax for the `ng-model` element. I'm following the pattern from the tutorial, so I am confident that is correct. Then, I made sure I closed the `<span>` properly, and I believe that checks out. I'm new to not only `angular-js`, but `javascript` as well (plus only passingly familiar with `html`), so I suspect this is where the problem lies. I'm not sure how to pin-point the problem. Is it glaring? Could someone point out what I've done wrong? Below is the entire `index.html` for reference.

```
<!doctype html5>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SpreedSheet Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="DataEntryCtrl">

   <span ng-repeat="entryField in entryFields">
      <input type="text" ng-model="entryField.ngmodel" placeholder="entryField.pHolder">
   </span>
   <div ng-view></div>
</div>

  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/services.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
  <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace this:

```
placeholder="entryField.pHolder"
```

with:

```
placeholder="{{entryField.pHolder}}"
```

I am not sure what do you use the tag "ng-model" for in this case.
But it should work then.

Comment: I had already tried the `{{ }}` syntax. I just get a literal again, this time wrapped in `{{ }}`

Comment: Just a sanity check - are you sure your controller is running?  maybe put a console.log in there?  It sounds like angular isn't processing the html at all

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle showing that paola's answer is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/FmAxE/ You must have an issue elsewhere, as @RoyTruelove suggests.

Comment: accepted, and I'll investigate what else might be the trouble.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem was that I had ng-app defined twice.